# Django. Make a many-page showcase

Tags: python, django, web

StackOverflow, I want to make a many-page showcase.

On the first page, it`ll be first 25 items, in the second - from 26 to 50 and so on.

But how can I do this?

here is urls.py:

```
products = Product.objects.order_by('-date')
urlpatterns = [
url(r' regexp ', ListView.as_view(queryset=products, template_name='shop/shop.html')),]
```

It must to asnwer the requests like this:
mysite.com/shop/2

and also display products[25*(request_number-1) : 25*request_number] items on page

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view ?

Comment: @Adrien Yep, I did and something goes wrong at `page = request.GET.get('page')`

Comment: @AdrienMatissart maybe change  `request.GET.get('shop' + request)`? my link looks like this: site.com/shop/2

Answer (score 1):

`ListView` can handle pagination for you, if you define its `paginate_by` parameter. Let's define all parameters in a new class inheriting from it:

```
class ProductsListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    ordering = '-date'
    paginate_by = 25
    template_name = 'shop/shop.html'
```

Then, all you need is to define a `page` parameter in your url pattern.
Technically, this works because [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.list.ListView) inherits from [`MultipleObjectMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#multipleobjectmixin)

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^shop/(?P<page>[0-9]+)/$', ProductListView.as_view())
]
```

Comment: sorry for another stupid question, but what do I have to do if I want to process my data? I have a function which translates [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] into [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, None, None]], how can i apply it to that?

Comment: Not sure to understand how this is related to your original question. But you could override the `get_queryset` method in `ListView` to define your own way to build the list of objects that will be rendered in the template.

Comment: Thanks again, u are the best!